# Correct way to take screenshots of fullcalendar timegrid view

Tags: reactjs, html2canvas

I have a problem with taking a screenshot using `html2canvas` module of my fullcalendar/timegrid view. Each time I download the image, the lines (stripes) of the calendar covers the event's div. I use the following code to generate the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMRMB.png), it consists of using both html2canvas and file-server modules:

```
html2canvas(document.querySelector('#timetable')).then(function(canvas) {

                console.log(canvas);
                saveAs(canvas.toDataURL(), 'file-name.png');
            });[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: You can post images using `Ctrl+G`, please avoid adding links next time.